# Enable/disable panel on click of button in jsf/primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Button called Add oncilck of add panel needs to be displayed and within the panel there is a cancel button onclick of cancel the panel should be closed my problem is onclicking the add button the panel is coming for a moment and disapperaring. actually i have incuded template_2.xhtml which has .. if i remove  from template_2.xhtml the panel is working fine but these warnings are coming like this The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within  i want both of things to work fine and warnings should not come .Here is my code`i know the problem that i am using 2 times form in 1 xhtml page but not able to overcome that help me out`
 `

```
     <h:commandButton value="Add" id="show"  action="#"  onclick="panelwv.show()" ></h:commandButton>
    <h:form>

        <p:panel id="panel" widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false"  header="Add Dependents">
             <h:panelGrid id="myPanel" columns="3" cellpadding="5" styleClass="text-input">


            <h:outputText value=""/>

              <h:outputLabel  value="Name" style="font-family: cursive;font-size: 18px;font-weight:normal;"/>  
              <h:inputText  id="name"  value="#{depco.depapp.dep.name}" styleClass="border" label="First Name" />
               <h:outputText value=""/>

              <h:outputLabel  value="Relationship" style="font-family: cursive;font-size: 18px;font-weight:normal;"/>  
              <h:inputText id="rel"  value="#{depco.depapp.dep.relationship}" styleClass="border" label="Relationship" />
               <h:outputText value=""/>



               <h:outputLabel  value="Date of Birth" style="font-family: cursive;font-size: 18px;font-weight:normal;"/>  
               <p:calendar id="dob"  value="#{depco.depapp.dep.dob}" showOn="button"  label="Date of Birth" />
               <h:outputText value=""/>


             <h:outputLabel value="Emp Id" />
             <h:selectOneMenu value="#{depco.depapp.dep.empId}"  > &nbsp;
                 <f:selectItems value="#{coemp.empapp.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"  var="emp" itemLabel="#{emp.empId}" itemValue="#{emp.empId}" />
                 <f:converter converterId="employeeConverter" />
             </h:selectOneMenu> 
               <h:outputText value=""/>


               <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{depco.createDepAction()}"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#" id="hide" onclick="panelwv.hide()" value="cancel"/> 


             </h:panelGrid>
                 </p:panel> 
    </h:form>
    `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF menu and submenu tags should be included within form tag .so i just mage a separate jsf file with some name(say xyz.xhtml) and i just included the xyz.xhtml in actual jsf page using

Answer (score 0):

Your Example is working fine for me, [using Primefaces 3.5 JSF 2.1.13].
It might be the problem with the buttons you used.

Usually `h:commandButton` will not do a Ajax submit, it submits the form untill you specify `f:ajax` explicitly, so that might be the reason the panel is coming and disappearing.

Use `p:commandButton` which does a ajax submit by default.or else use `f:ajax` with the `h:commandButton`.

Since you are not calling any ManagedBean's property or method from your `h:commandButton`s, you can even use `h:button`.

Comment: :i have included jsf page called template_2.xhtml there if i include <p:layout>...</p:layout>within <h:form>....</h:form>this error is coming and panel is getting displayed.i tried using p:commandButton same problem arising can you help me out with example